# Play More Than One Sound Files in Livecode

Tags: audio, livecode

I want to create a game with sound effects. When I start the game, the background music should be played until the game is over. When I click on something in the game (such as buttons), a sound effect should be played but the background music is stopped.

How can I make the background music play continuously while the sound effect from object is playing?

I already have these scripts...

Card script...

```
on openCard
   play "backgroundmusic.wav" looping
end openCard
```

Buttons (or any object)...

```
on mouseup
   play "sound.wav"
end mouseup
```

How to play these sounds together?

---

**Update**: I found a game uploaded to Game Jam. This game was ranked #1. When I play the game, the sound was amazing that it has background music and sound effects. But the owner of this game doesn't upload the livecode stack file in order to study it. The game was entitled [Space Shooter Game](http://itch.io/jam/the-very-first-livecode-game-jam/rate/12562). The sounds of this game is what I expect.

---

**Note:**
As what I figured out from the answers, using the `player` object can be work. But this requires QuickTime which I don't have that installed in my PC. I want also the sound to be able to play in mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, the soundChannel property has no effect in LiveCode and is only provided for Hypercard compatibility.

Currently on desktop there are two ways to do multi-channel sound: 1) play imported sounds as one channel, and use a player object as the second channel, or 2) use two player objects.

Typically, a good option is to import short sounds as sound effects into a stack that only play once, and reserve the player object for background music. Imported sounds usually play with the least latency, however, you cannot play multiple imported simultaneously -- attempting to play a second sound while a first is playing will stop the first to play the second.  If you have a need to play asynchronous sound effects, this option will not work; you must use a combination of playback options.

Multiple players can be used, but note that there can be some latency during the process of loading a sound (assigning a sound's filepath to a player) and playing it.

Also note that truly seamless playback of of a track is difficult if not impossible -- LiveCode will at some point become susceptible to some system event that will cause a slight pause between loops.  A while back, Trevor Devore made an addition to his Enhanced QuickTime external that enabled true seamless looping of audio.  However, with Apple getting rid QuickTime, it's unknown how much longer this option will be useful.

With the enhancements that the RunRev guys have been making to the engine, it's likely we'll see improvement with media playback and management, hopefully sooner rather than later.

Comment: I tried the `player` object but my sound doesn't play (commented also at hliljegren's answer). I don't know what's the problem even though I wait for the sound to load for a very long time.

Comment: What version of LiveCode are you using? In the latest releases (v. 6.7.1 and 7.0.1) a bug appeared that prevented the `start player` command from working. This bug has been reported and fixed for the upcoming 6.7.2 and 7.0.2. If you don't want to use the pre-release versions you can use the workaround `set the playRate of player "myplayer" to 1`.

Answer (score 0):

In the [LiveCode forums](http://forums.livecode.com/viewtopic.php?t=7194), they suggest using player objects on the card instead and telling them to play.

---

In HyperCard, you could set the `soundChannel` property for that. Have you checked in the LiveCode documentation whether it supports that? The docs for the `play` command and the `the sound` property might also help. Maybe those contain hints. FWIW, in HC

```
set the soundChannel to 1
play "BackgroundMusic"
set the soundChannel to 2
play "SoundEffect"
```

would play the sound effect and background music at the same time. Maybe that's how it works in LiveCode as well?

Comment: It doesn't work, the background music still stops after clicking on the button (sound effect).
Also, I am not using HyperCard.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use LiveCode that much, but since it is a clone of HyperCard, it usually works to just suggest whatever one does in HC :-) I guess here they decided to do their own thing.

Comment: Added a suggestion that I found by googling for `livecode play simultaneous audio`.

Answer (score 0):

The multimedia capabilities are a going through a transformation. Previously everything was built around QuickTime (well almost everything) and you needed to add a player control for each concurrent sound. Currently the whole foundation is changed as Apple dropped QuickTime, but assuming you develop for desktop you should still (again) be able to add a player object and then use:

```
start player "name of player"
```

You can also create player object dynamically by

```
create player "my player""
```

and then use

```
set the filename of player "my player to "/path/to/your/audio/file"
```

before staring your sound. And as long as you have different players for your different sounds they should play simultaneously.

Comment: I tried adding `player` object but now the background music doesn't play anymore. I think it's because my file is not supported for that player or something else. I am using `.wav` file as background music.

Comment: What platform are you on? The new player object should use the native player on each platform. So I can't see that waw should be a problem. BUT I've had problem if it had a strange sample rate with the old player.

Answer (score 0):

```
on openCard
  put specialFolderPath("engine") & "/soundfx/backgroundmusic.wav" into tSound
  mobilePlaySoundOnChannel tSound, "Background", "looping"
end openCard

on mouseup
   play "sound.wav"
end mouseup
```

Comment: Please don't just post code without any further explanation. Also, use a code block to format your code properly.